# How to retrieve the tomcat log file using java

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat7

I want to get the log file form tomcat .How to retrieve and get it downloaded from tomcat using java. I am using **Java6** and **Tomcat7**

Comment: Simply open the file; what do you want?

Comment: Are you talking about a standalone app or you want to do it from the application that's running on tomcat?

Comment: I am web application.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve log file using System.getProperty("catalina.base") + "/logs".

Comment: But programmatically how the file downloaded

Comment: You can get log files contains using System.getProperty("catalina.base") , then you can download that files using java.

Comment: Here the scenario is my server run at another location

Comment: What you exactly want? Are you want to download log files from another system.

Answer (score 0):

If security is not an issue, you can add tomcat log dir to tomcat web dir and enable file listing. and tomcat will play as an http server and log files are static files. you can list and download the log files.

---

Back to your original requirements, you want to download tomcat log files ( very likely via http) using java as client.

1) So first there should be a http server. you can use python. go into tomcat log dir and run `nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 > /dev/null &`
it will start a http server on current dir using port 8000

2) using your browser to open HOST_IP:8000 and check if the http server works. it should list all log files in the dir.

3) write your java code to connect to the http server and download the file. apache http client should do this job.

Comment: if you have the sample code post here so that I will get clear idea.